# Material for goalie leg pads

Tags: sewing, material-sourcing

What kind of material is used to make goalie leg pads? Some kind of synthetic leather?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://www.thegoalnet.com/forums/topic/844-my-homemade-ball-hockey-pads/) is a set someone made. They used **ballistic nylon** and **420D nylon**, and **high- and low-density EVA foams** for the padding. Materials that are of high quality and have a high wear resistance, but are relatively light-weight.

Do note that making goalie pads yourself is generally advised against online (for reasons similar to why DIY cycling helmets are not a particularly good idea, I assume).